# HTML5 video with audio separate cannot control volume

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I use video tag of html5 by separate audio from video like this code.

```
<video id="myvideo" controls >
  <source src="output.webm" type="video/webm">
    <audio id="myaudio" controls="">
        <source src="audio1.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    </audio>
</video>

<script>
    var myvideo = document.getElementById("myvideo");
    var myaudio = document.getElementById("myaudio");

    var change_time_state = true;

    myvideo.onplay = function(){
        myaudio.play();
        if(change_time_state){
            myaudio.currentTime = myvideo.currentTime;
            change_time_state = false;
        }
    }

    myvideo.onpause = function(){
        myaudio.pause();
        change_time_state = true;
    }
</script>
```

It can play video and audio but it cannot change audio volume. Can I fix it to change volume ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the MP4 video and check your source URL.

Answer (score 0):

You might be searching the DOM volume Property, check it in [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp)

In your case the solution is:

```
myaudio.volume = anynumber;
```

Must be a number between 0.0 and 1.0.

Example values:

> 1.0 is highest volume (100%. This is default)
>
> 0.5 is half volume (50%)
>
> 0.0 is silent (same as mute)